# How to instantiate a page object model in a Beforetest method and use the instance in different test methods

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

l am having to repeat instantiating a particular page objects in different test methods. l was thinking if there is a way to instantiate the page object once and use that instance in all the different test methods. Below is my code for clarity

```
    @Test
    public void FilterByAll() {
         KYCScreenPage kycScreen = new KYCScreenPage(_driver);
         kycScreen.KycScreenNav().click();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void KycDownload() {
        
     KYCScreenPage kycScreen = new KYCScreenPage(_driver);
     kycScreen.KycScreenNav().click();
     kycScreen.KYCDownload().click();
     
    }
```

l want to instantiate KYCScreenPage once and use the instance in all the test methods.

Comment: Can't you just istantiate KYCScreenPage as a class attribute, then use it in the methods?

Comment: @Rob l did that but it gave a nullreference error for the _driver. The driver is instantiated in the base class that is extended by the class these methods are written in